# adjacency linked list C++ display

Tags: c++, linked-list, adjacency-list

I have created an adjacency linked list to show flights between cities. The program reads from 2 files, one contains names of cities and the other one contains source and destination of different flights. I have created an array for the cities served and a linked list of connecting cities for each city index of the array. However, I'm having trouble printing out the list. My out put looks like this:

```
Origin --  Dest     ---      Flight No. --       Price  

NYC    ---          Chicago  --        3123   ----             123  
NYC    ----        Miami    ----        2123      ----          543    
NYC         ----     Seattle   ---       9283        ----        243
```

I want to know if I can print out the origin city just once.

Here's my code for the struct and other stuff:

```
 struct flight
 {
       int fNumber;
       string source;
       string dest;
       int price;    
 }
```

overload operator for output
`p.source` is the origin, `p.dest` is the destination and so on

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const flight & p)
 {
       os <<"From "<< p.source << " to: ";
       int diff=0;
       diff= 35- p.source.length();
       os << fixed<< setw(diff)<<right<< p.dest;
       os << setw(10)<<right<<p.fNumber;
       os << setw(10)<<right<<p.price;
       return os;
 }
```

and the display function

```
void flightMap::display()
{
      cout<<setw(15)<<"Origin   "<<setw(30)<<"Destination"<<setw(12)<<"Flight     "<<setw(13)    <<"Price     "<<endl;
      cout<<"================================================================="<<endl;

      for (int i=0; i<number;  i++)
      {
            flightRecord[i].display();
      }
}
```

I want my output to look like this

```
Origin Dest Flight No. Price

NYC Chicago 3123 123  
  ----   Miami 2123 543  
  ----  Seattle 9283 243
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but it probably needs a bit of reorganization of your code. The first thing that has to change is this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, const flight & p)
```

This is the standard way of printing but it's not really good enough here because there is no way of telling this function whether to print the source city or not. So lets write a different function

```
void printFlight(ostream & os, const flight & p, bool printSource)
{
   if (printSource)
       os <<"From "<< p.source << " to: ";
   else
       os <<"From --- to: ";
   ...
}
```

Now you can use that function in your loop as long as you remember what the last source city you printed was. If the last source city is different from the current source city then you print the source city, otherwise not. Something like this

```
string lastSource = "";
for (int i=0; i<number;  i++)
{
    printFlight(cout, flightRecord[i], flightRecord[i].source != lastSource);
    lastSource = flightRecord[i].source;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot john, well i removed "from p.source to" from my overloaded operator <<, so that will only display the last 3 variables and then i used your advice by creating a last source city in my loop, works perfectly, thank again!